# Error getting SVN repo of Liferay in Eclipse

Tags: java, svn, liferay, subclipse, eclipse-3.5

Im using Eclipse Galileo and have installed Subclipse. I looked at the svn repo url at http://www.liferay.com/web/brian.chan/blog/-/blogs/changes-to-anonymous-access-to-liferay-s-svn and then tried to get Liferay from their SVN repository in Eclipse, using `svn://svn.liferay.com/repos/public --username guest`,but i get the following error message:

```
Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
svn: Cant connect to host 'svn.liferay.com':No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Any way to fix this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try removing '--username guest' from the URL string. I could connect successfully to it using Eclipse and SubClipse plugin. Add the 'guest' user with empty password in the credential form in the next step. It would also be appropriate to check that your DNS server and internet connectivity are working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Benjamin. Even if i remove the username part and just use svn://svn.liferay.com/repos/public, i get the same error.

Comment: I have setup Eclipse to use the JavaHL client in the Eclipse->Team->SVN preferecens. Do you have the same? Do you see 205.134.240.1.1 when you ping svn.liferay.com?

Answer (score 0):

It works now ! :).Just had to change svn://svn.liferay.com/repos/public to http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public.